# R ggplot2 stat_summary legend mean additional to groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've plotted the mean for the whole study population (black line) and for men and women separately.

```
plotYYIR1<- ggplot(data=YYIR1Long, aes(x=TimeValue, y=YYIR1Value)) +
  labs(x="Week number", y="YYIR1 distance run (m)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust=0))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"))+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "point", size=2) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", size=0.7) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "point", size=2, aes(shape=Sex,colour=Sex)) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Male"=17, "Female"=15))+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", size=0.7, aes(colour=Sex)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#009CEF", "#CC0000"))+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width =2)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width =2, aes(colour=Sex))
plotYYIR1
```

The legend only shows the genders, could someone help me with adding the black line and points in the legend for the whole group?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `aes()` to get a legend for the black line/points. If you want the legend to be for lines/shapes combined you can turn off the legend for shapes by adding `guide = F` to `scale_shape_manual` and then use `override.aes` in `guides` to specify the shapes in the legend:

```
 ggplot(data=YYIR1Long, aes(x=TimeValue, y=YYIR1Value)) +
  labs(x="Week number", y="YYIR1 distance run (m)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust=0))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"))+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "point", size=2, aes(colour = "mean")) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", size=0.7, aes(colour = "mean")) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "point", size=2, aes(shape=Sex,colour=Sex)) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Male"=17, "Female"=15, "mean"=16), guide = F)+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", size=0.7, aes(colour=Sex)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#009CEF", "#CC0000", "#000000"))+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width =2, aes(colour = "mean"))+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width =2, aes(colour=Sex)) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c("Male"=17, "Female"=15, "mean"=16))))
```